# React.js pattern for component that encapsulates load/save from db?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a React component that can capture address information from a user.  This component will be invoked as part of a larger page of information.  Since the address database access has its own backend endpoint, I'd like to encapsulate the load/save into the Address component.

If the "save" button is part of the component this is easy.  Something like this:

```js
// Standalone with save button inside AddressBlock

class AddressBlock extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isSaving: false,
      isLoading: false
    };
  }
  
  async componentDidMount() {
    getAddress(this.props.address.id)
      .then( address => this.props.setAddress(address) )
      .then( () => this.setState({ isLoading: false }) );
  }
  
  async handleSave() {
    this.setState({ isSaving: true });
    saveAddress(this.props.address)
      .then( () => this.setState({ isSaving: false }) );
  }

  validateForm() {
    return this.props.address.street && this.props.address.city && ...
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( { this.state.isLoading ? "Loading" :
      <div>
        <FormControl
          id="street"
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          value={this.props.address.street}
        />
        // etc for city, state, postcode

        <SpinnerButton 
          onClick={this.handleSave}
          spin={this.state.isSaving}
          disabled={!this.validateForm()}
        >
          Save
        </SpinnerButton>
      </div>
    });
  }
}
```

This keeps its state information in an ancestor, with address passed in from this.props.address and with onChange passed in as well.  So I think that's in the top-down React spirit.

But what about when this AddressBlock is part of a larger page that includes other objects, and there's one "save" button to save the whole page?  That save button should be enabled only when all the child forms are valid.  And, I'd like to preserve the encapsulation that the AddressBlock knows how to do its own saving; but as others have noted, it's not very React-y to pass a "save" event down to the AddressBlock.

I could move the save functionality up to the parent, but for encapsulation and reuse it seems that the AddressBlock should keep that to itself.

The best I've been able to come up with is to have the AddressBlock register callbacks to its parent, as below, but it feels very clunky.

There must be a better way -- what am I missing?

```js
// Not very pretty way to take the save button up to parent

class AddressBlock extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    ...
    this.props.registerSaveFunc(this.handleSave)
    this.props.registerValidateFunc(this.validateForm)
  }
  
  render() {
    ...
    // no Button in AddressBlock (moved to parent)
  }
}

class CaptureSeveralThings extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      address: { id: this.props.addressId },
      addressSaveFunc: null,
      addressValidateFunc: null,
      documents: [],
      documentsSaveFunc: null,
      documentsValidateFunc: null,
      // etc where each knows how to load and save itself
    };
  }
  
  handleSave = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
      this.state.addressSaveFunc,
      this.state.documentsSaveFunc
    ]);
  }

  validateForm = () => this.state.addressValidateFunc() && this.state.documentsValidateFunc();
  
  setAddress = async (address) => this.setState({ address });

  registerAddressSaveFunc = async (f) => this.setState({ addressSaveFunc: f });
  // etc. for SaveFunc and ValidateFunc for each component

  handleAddrChange = async (event) => ... etc.
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <AddressBlock
          address={this.props.address}
          setAddress={this.setAddress}
          registerSaveFunc={this.registerAddressSaveFunc}
          registerValidateFunc={this.registerAddressValidateFunc}
          onChange={this.handleAddrChange}
        />
         <DocumentsBlock
          documents={this.props.documents}
          setDocs={this.setDocs}
          registerSaveFunc={this.registerDocsSaveFunc}
          registerValidateFunc={this.registerDocsValidateFunc}
          onChange={this.handleAddrChange}
        /> 

        // simplified for this example
        // to get the spinner functionality would need to register even more callbacks for when each Block is saving        
        <Button
           onClick={this.handleSave}
           disabled={this.validateForm}
        >
          Save All
        </Button>
      </div>
        
    )
  }
  
  
}
```

Comment: How come you're using async functions without `await`?

Comment: @SterlingArcher Wherever the later thing depends on the earlier Promise resolving, it uses ".then".  If it doesn't then it's fire-and-forget, and if someone invoking needs to wait for the result it can do that.  

(Also this is a simplified example to ask about the child-callback issue, not a paste of running code, so I may have missed something.)

Comment: @SterlingArcher ah wait I see what you mean - since it's returning a Promise it doesn't have to be async.  Good point.